# hide "Affirm" payment gateway in cart for a specific product id

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've successfully hidden "Affirm" payment gateway for a specific product on the checkout Page. But the affirm Option still visible in the Cart Page. How to hide this if a specific item is in the cart? The content is located in `p#learn-more.affirm-as-low-as` block if that's useful. [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/132j74k)

```
<p id="learn-more" class="affirm-as-low-as" data-amount="32500" data-affirm-color="blue" data-learnmore-show="true" data-page-type="cart">Starting at <span class="affirm-ala-price">$30</span>/mo with <span class="__affirm-logo __affirm-logo-blue __ligature__affirm_full_logo__ __processed">Affirm</span>. <a class="affirm-modal-trigger" aria-label="Learn more about Affirm Financing (opens in modal)" href="javascript:void(0)">Learn more</a></p>
```

Comment: Hide something with CSS/jQuery is never a good solution, because anyone with a little knowledge can make it visible again. Since it is a payment method, the `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` hook, where you unset the payment gateway based on certain conditions sounds like the only right and correct solution.

Comment: @7uc1f3r  Yes, that's actually what I did (via plugin) which unsets the affirm payment for a specific product id. The payment option is no longer showing on the cart page which is good. But apparently a part or remnants of this code are still showing in the cart page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution is to *hide* it via `css`. Based on the details you've supplement, you can essentially hide that element for your users by adding this piece of stylesheet:

```
* #learn-more.affirm-as-low-as {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Since you are using wordpress, there are various ways on how you can add some custom stylesheets on your website in case you didn't know how. You start by reading this [article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/)